# Kinect for Xbox One (+ adapter) and Windows 10

Tags: unity, windows, kinect, hololens

Can I use Kinect Xbox One (with adapter like Kinect for Windows V2 device), SDK 2.0, to build applications on Windows 10? I've read the requirements for Kinect and it lists only Win 8.0 and Win 8.1.

I'd like to use Kinect Xbox One device with Unity 3D and Hololens. Before I buy the device I'd appreciate if anyone can share some experiance or at least to confirm that would be possible to develop apps with Kinect for Xbox One on Win10?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just google what you asked "Kinect Xbox One device with Unity 3D and Hololens" and a lot of useful places come up. From a quick skim it seems Unity3D and Hololens work together at least.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can confirm that the second generation Kinect works with Unity on Windows 10. I've worked on two game projects that use this setup: [Glimpse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sn9JEMfEZg) and Pixelate (both were originally developed on Windows 8 / 8.1, and upgrading to Windows 10 or copying them to a Windows 10 machine has not resulted in any problems I've experienced)

One heads-up: the Kinect is *very* picky about what USB ports it will work with. It needs a USB 3.0 port with unusually high bandwidth - so if your controller is weak or daisy-chained through a HUB it will likely refuse to cooperate or suffer low framerate. So far my best experience has been with USB 3 controllers embedded in the PC's motherboard - I've yet to find an extension card the Kinect will work with reliably & without complaint.

Also, anecdotally, I've had better luck with the Xbox One Kinect plus the separate USB adapter, than with the integrated "Kinect for Windows" model that has this built-in. Might just be that we had a bad unit, but we experienced periodic crashes with the latter.